# Fastest way to get Mean of a subset in a 6-dim matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia

I have a Float64 array `x` with 6 dimensions of [10,10,100,4,4,1000].

I want to take the mean of a subset of this array, for instance:

```
x = rand(10,10,100,4,4,1000)   #Dummy array
r = squeeze(mean(x[:,:,1:80,:,:,56:800],(1,2,3,4,5)),(1,2,3,4,5))
```

This currently takes a long time to complete, I assume due to the copy process in matrix indexing.

Is there a faster way to do this?

Edit: I'm happy to modify the array itself, and was wondering if there's a multidimensional equivalent of `pop!`?

Comment: for some reason this is way quicker on juia 0.4 than 0.5 or 0.6 ... not sure why

Comment: That would explain a lot.. I transitioned from one server with 0.4 to a new one on 0.5 and assumed it wouldn't be a general issue, so assumed it was server specific

Comment: Have you tried using view to avoid the copy?

Comment: I haven't tried view.. I'll look into that. But @AlexanderMorley has hit on a good point... this example takes ~170 seconds in 0.5 and 0.6, but 1 second in 0.4.7.... I've opened another more specific thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40351485/why-is-indexing-a-large-matrix-170x-slower-slower-in-julia-0-5-0-than-0-4-7