# Why is indexing a large matrix 170x slower slower in Julia 0.5.0 than 0.4.7?

Tags: matrix, julia

Indexing large matrixes seems to be taking FAR longer in 0.5 and 0.6 than 0.4.7.

For instance:

```
x = rand(10,10,100,4,4,1000)   #Dummy array

tic()
r = squeeze(mean(x[:,:,1:80,:,:,56:800],(1,2,3,4,5)),(1,2,3,4,5))
toc()
```

Julia 0.5.0 -> elapsed time: 176.357068283 seconds

Julia 0.4.7 -> elapsed time: 1.19991952 seconds

---

Edit: as per requested, I've updated the benchmark to use `BenchmarkTools.jl` and wrap the code in a function:

```
using BenchmarkTools
function testf(x)
    r = squeeze(mean(x[:,:,1:80,:,:,56:800],(1,2,3,4,5)),(1,2,3,4,5));
end

x = rand(10,10,100,4,4,1000)   #Dummy array
@benchmark testf(x)
```

In 0.5.0 I get the following (with huge memory usage):

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          1
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  23.36 gb
  allocs estimate:  1043200022
  minimum time:     177.94 s (1.34% GC)
  median time:      177.94 s (1.34% GC)
  mean time:        177.94 s (1.34% GC)
  maximum time:     177.94 s (1.34% GC)
```

In 0.4.7 I get:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          11
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  727.55 mb
  allocs estimate:  79
  minimum time:     425.82 ms (0.06% GC)
  median time:      485.95 ms (11.31% GC)
  mean time:        482.67 ms (10.37% GC)
  maximum time:     503.27 ms (11.22% GC)
```

---

Edit: Updated to use `sub` in 0.4.7 and `view` in 0.5.0

```
using BenchmarkTools
function testf(x)
    r = mean(sub(x, :, :, 1:80, :, :, 56:800));
end

x = rand(10,10,100,4,4,1000)   #Dummy array
@benchmark testf(x)
```

In 0.5.0 it ran for >20 mins and gave:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          1
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  53.75 gb
  allocs estimate:  2271872022
  minimum time:     407.64 s (1.32% GC)
  median time:      407.64 s (1.32% GC)
  mean time:        407.64 s (1.32% GC)
  maximum time:     407.64 s (1.32% GC)
```

In 0.4.7 I get:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  samples:          5
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
  memory estimate:  1.28 kb
  allocs estimate:  34
  minimum time:     1.15 s (0.00% GC)
  median time:      1.16 s (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        1.16 s (0.00% GC)
  maximum time:     1.18 s (0.00% GC)
```

---

This seems repeatable on other machines, so an issue has been opened: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19174

Comment: Please read the [performance tips](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/performance-tips/). In particular, don't benchmark in global scope.

Comment: also, consider benchmarking code with [BenchmarkTools.jl](https://github.com/JuliaCI/BenchmarkTools.jl) instead of `tic`/`toc`. the latter is less reliable than the former.

Comment: and for what it is worth, you are not indexing a _matrix_. you are indexing and operating on a _multidimensional array_ which is a much larger and more complicated object.

Comment: I appreciate the pointers/clarifications, but it's not helping me with the core issue.. I've just updated the benchmarking to what you suggested, but in 0.5.0 it literally didn't finish for 10 minutes, so I interrupted it. I would appreciate if someone could validate that this is repeatable

Comment: I just left 0.5.0 running to get stats and added it above

Comment: wouldn't it make more sense to benchmark something like `y = view(x, :, :, 1:80, :, :, 56:800); mean(y)` ? that avoids an array copy.

Comment: I'm just testing `r = mean(view(x, :, :, 1:80, :, :, 56:800))` and it's been running for about 5 minutes.. still seems slow in 0.5.0 (can't test view in 0.4.7)

Comment: in 0.4.7 the command is `sub`

Comment: Updated to use `sub` & `view`. 0.5.0 ran for 10 mins and I gave up

Comment: I finally got a benchmark result out in 0.5.0 for `view`. See above

Comment: I'm not sure what the underlying problem is, but it appears to be fixed on master.

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/19097

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT 17 March 2017** This regression is fixed in Julia v0.6.0. The discussion still applies if using older versions of Julia.

Try running this crude script in both Julia v0.4.7 and v0.5.0 (change `sub` to `view`):

```
using BenchmarkTools

function testf()
    # set seed
    srand(2016)

    # test array
    x = rand(10,10,100,4,4,1000)

    # extract array view
    y = sub(x, :, :, 1:80, :, :, 56:800)   # julia v0.4
    #y = view(x, :, :, 1:80, :, :, 56:800)  # julia v0.5

    # wrap mean(y) into a function
    z() = mean(y)

    # benchmark array mean
    @time z() 
    @time z() 
end

testf()
```

My machine:

```
julia> versioninfo() 
Julia Version 0.4.7 
Commit ae26b25 (2016-09-18 16:17 UTC) 
Platform Info: 
  System: Darwin (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) 
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4870HQ CPU @ 2.50GHz 
  WORD_SIZE: 64 
  BLAS: libopenblas (USE64BITINT DYNAMIC_ARCH NO_AFFINITY Haswell) 
  LAPACK: libopenblas64_ 
  LIBM: libopenlibm 
  LLVM: libLLVM-3.3
```

My output, **Julia v0.4.7**:

```
1.314966 seconds (246.43 k allocations: 11.589 MB)
1.017073 seconds (1 allocation: 16 bytes)
```

My output, **Julia v0.5.0**:

```
417.608056 seconds (2.27 G allocations: 53.749 GB, 0.75% gc time)
410.918933 seconds (2.27 G allocations: 53.747 GB, 0.72% gc time)
```

It would seem that you may have discovered a performance regression. Consider filing an [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues).

Comment: aaaaand I am too slow :(

Comment: aaaand you [beat me to it](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/19174) hahaha :)

Comment: ah ha! Only by a minute or two! Thanks for checking, I appreciate the quick response... It's a very surprisingly significant regression!

Comment: in case you care, at least our timing results are pretty consistent. we both get ~1 sec for v0.4.7, ~408 sec for v0.5.

Comment: For what it's worth, this regression is fixed on the 0.6-alpha.  It's even 3x faster than 0.4.7 on my machine.